# How can I get the results of a CHKDSK that run on boot?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

## **Problematic**

> `CHKDSK` ran when my machine rebooted, and displayed some stuff.
>   Problem  is I have no idea what it displayed, since it then proceeded
>   to reboot  the machine when it was done. How do I get it to stop,
>   pause or  otherwise let me see what it did ?
>
> chkdsk cannot run because the volume is in use by another process mean
>   ?, CHKDSK needs exclusive access to the disk it’s checking if it’s
>   been instructed to attempt fixes or repairs. If that disk is your
>   Windows drive (C:), CHKDSK can’t have exclusive access, because
>   Windows is using that drive simply to run your system.

[image]

When we restart, the CHKDSK is performed before Windows is loaded.

[image]

`CHKDSK` runs as it normally does, and when it completes, it reboots the system – which, of course, causes any progress or results that might have been displayed on-screen to disappear.

In order to create a helpful tool for maintenance of my hard drives to check, fix and repair them for errors.

I did this batch

```
@echo off
Title Check Disk drives for errors and fix them by Hackoo 2016
mode con cols=67 lines=5 & Color 0A
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "TmpLog=%Tmp%\TmpLog.txt"
set "Log=%~dp0%computername%_%~n0.txt"
If Exist "%TmpLog%" Del "%TmpLog%"
If exist "%Log%" Del "%Log%"
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >nul 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                        **************************************
ECHO                         Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                        **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          START         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
( Echo Scan started @ & Date /T & Time /T & echo ************************ ) > "%TmpLog%"
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" ^|find /i ":"') do (
    set "fix=%%i"
        Call :Affich !fix!
    (
        echo !fix! Drive 
        echo ************************
        echo(
        (echo O
        echo Y) | CHKDSK !fix! /f 
        echo(
        echo ************************
    )>> "%TmpLog%"
)
EndLocal
Goto Question
Exit /b

:Question
( echo Scan finished @ & Date /T & Time /T & echo ************************ )>> "%TmpLog%"
CMD /U /C Type "%TmpLog%" > "%Log%"
If Exist "%TmpLog%" Del "%TmpLog%"
(
    echo    Answ = MsgBox("Did you want to reboot the computer to complete the scanning ?",VbYesNo+VbQuestion,"Reboot the computer to check hard disk drives for errors by Hackoo"^)
    echo    If Answ = VbYes then 
    echo        wscript.Quit(0^)
    echo    Else
    echo        wscript.Quit(1^)
    echo    End If
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"

Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
IF "%errorlevel%" EQU "1" (start "" "%Log%" & Exit ) else (goto Shutdown)

:Shutdown 
echo(
cls
echo(
echo     Save your work - Reboot of your computer in 20 seconds
echo(
echo   Enregistrer vos documents - Redemarrage du PC dans 20 seconds 
Shutdown.exe /r /t 20 /c "Enregistrer vos documents - Redemarrage du PC dans 20 secondes"
start "" %Log%
pause>nul
exit /b

:Affich
Cls
echo(
echo                ***********************************
Echo                 Please wait a while Scanning "%~1"
echo                ***********************************
Timeout /T 2 /nobreak>nul
exit /b
```

So, my question is : ***How can i get the results of a `CHKDSK` that run on boot by batch or powershell ?***

Comment: For who downvote this question tell me why ?

Comment: Not sure but the log might be in the system's event log... Perhaps you might find the answer [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/272244) or [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/7e03326d-126a-4801-934a-c979acb53ebf/what-is-the-location-of-the-chkdskexe-log-file-in-both-windows-7-and-windows-xp?forum=w7itprogeneral)...

Comment: Anyway, +1 for your efforts and for a nice batch you've done. And yes, IMHO your question is truly pertinent. Congrats.

Comment: @statosdotcom Thank you ! for your support and for your understood ! and remark that i found by my self the answer of this question see it below. And of course thanks to **Ansgar Wiechers** that point my searching in the right direction that i share it for the community !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/848406):

```
get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname="Application"; id="1001"}| ?{$_.providername –match "wininit"} | fl timecreated, message | out-file Desktop\CHKDSKResults.txt
```

In batch file we can do like that:

```
@echo off
set "Log=%tmp%\CHKDSKResults.txt"
If Exist "%Log%" del "%Log%"
Powershell -Command "& "Get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname='Application'; id='1001'}^|?{$_.providername -match 'wininit'} ^| fl timecreated, message ^| out-file '%Log%'"
Start "" "%Log%"
```

***EDIT : On 27/07/2016 The final code :***

```
@echo off
Title Check Disk drives for errors and fix them by Hackoo 2016
mode con cols=67 lines=5 & Color 0A
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & get admin rights
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
set "TmpLog=%Tmp%\TmpLog.txt"
set "Log=%~dp0%computername%_%~n0.txt"
set "MyVBSFile=%~dp0%~n0_On_Boot.vbs"
set "Value=CHKDSK_ON_BOOT"
Set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"
If Exist "%TmpLog%" Del "%TmpLog%"
If exist "%Log%" Del "%Log%"
REM  --> Check for permissions
Reg query "HKU\S-1-5-19\Environment" >nul 2>&1
REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
Echo.
ECHO                        **************************************
ECHO                         Running Admin shell... Please wait...
ECHO                        **************************************

    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params = %*:"=""
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
::          START         ::
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
( Echo Scan started @ & Date /T & Time /T & echo ************************ ) > "%TmpLog%"
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f "tokens=2" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk where "drivetype=3" ^|find /i ":"') do (
    set "fix=%%i"
        Call :Affich !fix!
    (
        echo !fix! Drive 
        echo ************************
        echo(
        (echo O
        echo Y) | CHKDSK !fix! /f 
        echo(
        echo ************************
    )>> "%TmpLog%"
)
EndLocal
Goto Question
Exit /b
::******************************************************************
:Question
( echo Scan finished @ & Date /T & Time /T & echo ************************ )>> "%TmpLog%"
CMD /U /C Type "%TmpLog%" > "%Log%"
If Exist "%TmpLog%" Del "%TmpLog%"
(
    echo    Answ = MsgBox("Did you want to reboot the computer to complete the scanning ?",VbYesNo+VbQuestion,"Reboot the computer to check hard disk drives for errors by Hackoo"^)
    echo    If Answ = VbYes then 
    echo        wscript.Quit(0^)
    echo    Else
    echo        wscript.Quit(1^)
    echo    End If
)>"%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"

Cscript /nologo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs"
IF "%errorlevel%" EQU "1" ( goto AddKey ) else ( goto Shutdown )
::******************************************************************
:Shutdown
echo(
cls
echo(
echo     Save your work - Reboot of your computer in 120 seconds
echo(
echo   Enregistrer vos documents - Redemarrage du PC dans 120 seconds 
Call:AddKey && Shutdown.exe /r /t 120 /c "Enregistrer vos documents - Redemarrage du PC dans 120 secondes"
pause>nul
exit /b
::******************************************************************
:Affich
Cls
echo(
echo                ***********************************
Echo                 Please wait a while Scanning "%~1"
echo                ***********************************
Timeout /T 2 /nobreak>nul
exit /b
::******************************************************************
:AddKey
reg query "%key%" /v "%Value%" >nul 2>&1
If "%errorlevel%" EQU "0" ( Goto :EOF
    ) Else (
    reg add "%Key%" /v "%Value%" /t REG_SZ /d "%MyVBSFile%">nul
    (
        echo Option Explicit
        echo 'Run as Admin
        echo If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate"^) Then
        echo    CreateObject("Shell.Application"^).ShellExecute DblQuote(WScript.FullName^) _
        echo    , DblQuote(WScript.ScriptFullName^) ^& " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
        echo     WScript.Quit
        echo End If
        echo Dim ws,PSCommand,LogFile,ret
        echo LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, "."^)^) ^& "txt"
        echo set ws = createobject("wscript.shell"^)
        echo PSCommand = "cmd /c Powershell -Command ""& ""Get-winevent -FilterHashTable @{logname='Application'; id='1001'}^|?{$_.providername -match 'wininit'} ^| fl timecreated, message ^| out-file "^& SimpleQuote(LogFile^) ^&""
        echo ret = ws.run(PScommand,0,True^)
        echo ws.run DblQuote(LogFile^)
        echo '**************************************
        echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
        echo    DblQuote = chr(34^) ^& Str ^& chr(34^)
        echo End function
        echo '**************************************
        echo Function SimpleQuote(Str^)
        echo    SimpleQuote = ChrW(39^) ^& Str ^& ChrW(39^)
        echo End Function
        echo '**************************************
    )>"%MyVBSFile%"
start "" "%Log%"
)   
Exit /b
::*******************************************************************
```

Answer (score 5):

The information is [recorded in the eventlog](https://superuser.com/q/214209). You should be able to obtain it like this (using PowerShell):

```
Get-EventLog -LogName Application -Source Wininit |
    Where-Object { $_.Message -like '*checking file system*' } |
    Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Descending |
    Select-Object -First 1 -Expand Message
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply this a good idea ,,i will work on it, but i wonder why this question is downvoted, i don't understand why, is it a no good question asked ? should i delete it in this case ? please i need your advice Thank you again !

Comment: None of the downvotes is mine, so I could only speculate about the reasons, which I won't do.

Comment: I didn't say that the downvote is coming from you :) but i wonder when somebody downvote a question or an answer tell us why to avoid next time the same mistake if i made of couse.just all and thank you again for your help.
I really appreciated !